# Compilation of OpenCV v4.5.1 using CMake on NVIDIA GTX 1660 Super / Windows10

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, cuda, nvidia

I'm trying to use CMake to compile OpenCV v4.5.1 for my 1660 Super. I have installed CUDA Toolkit v12.0 and CUDNN v8.7.0.84 as per the instructions on NVIDIA's site. For the record, I'm following [these](https://learnopencv.com/how-to-use-opencv-dnn-module-with-nvidia-gpu-on-windows/) instructions.

I'm using my own Anaconda Python3.10 interpreter and am encountering the following error when using the Configuration tool of CMake.

```
CMake Error at modules/dnn/CMakeLists.txt:39 (message):
  DNN: CUDA backend requires cuDNN.  Please resolve dependency or disable
  OPENCV_DNN_CUDA=OFF


Registering hook 'INIT_MODULE_SOURCES_opencv_dnn': C:/Users/testbench/ocv/opencv/modules/dnn/cmake/hooks/INIT_MODULE_SOURCES_opencv_dnn.cmake
opencv_dnn: filter out cuda4dnn source code
rgbd: CERES support is disabled. Ceres Solver is Required for Posegraph optimization
CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVGenSetupVars.cmake:54 (message):
  CONFIGURATION IS NOT SUPPORTED: validate setupvars script in install
  directory
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:985 (include)
```

Please let me know if there is any more information that I can provide to assist in debugging.

Comment: Did you pass exactly the same command line arguments on step #5 as the instruction? I think you should show a little more context in your output. I expect there is more info above the part you added.

Comment: (1) update to 4.7.0 (2) investigate why cmake (the cmakefile) doesn't find cuDNN

Comment: HI @drescherjm I'm using CMake GUI which is why I'm not showing the rest of the details.

Comment: It still lets you copy the text error messages from from the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some troubleshooting, this seems to be the solution:

1. The official NVIDIA instructions asked me to copy the `lib`, `bin` and `include` folders of the CUDNN files into `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA\CUDNN\v8.7\`.
2. I have now copied the respective `lib`, `bin` and `include` folders to where CUDA was installed, at `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.0`.

From this, I get the following line in the CMake GUI:

```
Found CUDNN: C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v12.0/lib/x64/cudnn.lib
```